# Есть ли лишнее копирование в std::optional? C++

Tags: c++, optional, перемещение

Открыл для себя такую полезную штуку, как `std::optional` и `std::expected`. При прочтении документации по методу `or_else()` заметил, что он возвращает optional по значению. Значит ли это, что при каждом вызове or_else(), если optional содержит значение, то все его содержимое копируется/перемещается в новый экземпляр при возврате из функции? Например такой код:

```
// Методы хотят добавить в С++23, но, предположим, есть свой optional с такими методами
// Пусть foo() возвращает валидный std::optional
auto opt = foo().or_else([]{std::cout << "Invalid\n";})
                .or_else([]{std::cout << "Invalid 2\n";});
// Перемещение содержимого optional при возврате значения из or_else()
// При условии, что optional содержит значение
```

И если из-за ref-квалификаторов с перемещаемыми объектами все нормально, то что делать с объектами, которые хранят большое количество данных на стеке в полях класса? Их ведь не переместить, они будут копироваться в новый optional

Comment: возможно, компилятор просто сделает оптимизацию. Как c copy elision.  С другой стороны много данных хранить в переменных класса, объект которого сохраняется на стеке - ещё то удовольствие.  Много то не сохранишь

Comment: @KoVadim согласен, но вдруг кто-то решит так сделать. И мне интересно застрахован ли optional от такого или же программист просто "стреляет себе в ногу"

Comment: в с++ компилятор по умолчанию считает, что программист умный и умеет читать документацию/смотреть код.

Answer (score 0):

Лишнее копирование/перемещение не запрещено, а даже требуется, и может быть исключено разве что через "as-if" правило.

Лишнее копирование/перемещение запрещено для случая `optional` не содержащего значение, если там внутри `return` неименованной переменной.

В общем случае оптимизация вряд ли возможна для с lvalue `optional`, т.к. после `or_else` можно получить независимые копии объекта, каждая со своим состоянием.

Для rvalue (т.е. для `...::or_else(...) &&`) принципиально можно сделать оптимизацию в общем случае, трансформировав в:

```
void or_else(F f) {
 if (!*this)
 { 
    *this = f();
 }
} // далее используем старый объект как якобы новый
```

И, возможно, какой-то будущий стандарт будет разрешать/требовать такую оптимизацию, как C++17 требует RVO, а предыдущие разрешают.